# Image loading speed

Tags: javascript, html

how to display image loading speed in html and JavaScript ? I have got image size and my internet speed then time also.But i don't know how can i get count value in parameter of putimage and how can i implement this code....

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function putImage( iterations, update ) 
{
       var index = 0,count = 0,
            timer = window.setInterval( check, 1000 ); //check every 1 seconds




//calculating size of the image....
            function getRandomString( sizeInMb ) 
                    {
                        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~!@#$%^&*()_+`-=[]\{}|;':,./<>?", //random data prevents gzip effect
                            iterations = sizeInMb * 1024 * 1024, //get byte count
                            result = '';
                        for( var index = 0; index < iterations; index++ ) 
                        {
                            result += chars.charAt( Math.floor( Math.random() * chars.length ) );
                        };     
                        return result;
                    };

                                //showing file size....
                                if(window.ActiveXObject)
                                    {
                                        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                                        var filepath = document.getElementById('select_image').value;
                                        var thefile = fso.getFile(filepath);
                                        var sizeinbytes = thefile.size;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        var sizeinbytes = document.getElementById('select_image').files[0].size;
                                    }

                                // var fSExt = new Array('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB');
                                var fSExt = 'KB';
                                fSize = sizeinbytes; i=0;
                                while(fSize>900)
                                {
                                    fSize/=1024;i++;
                                }
                                //alert((Math.round((fSize*100)/100)*1024)+' '+fSExt);  //showing total image size...



//calculating internet speed....
        var speed = 0;
        check();
        //alert("sss"+speed)
        function check() 
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                url = '?cache=' + Math.floor( Math.random() * 10000 ), //random number prevents url caching
                data = getRandomString( 1 ), //1 meg POST size handled by all servers
                startTime;
                speed;
                count;

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function ( event ) 
            {
                if( xhr.readyState == 4 ) 
                {
                    speed = Math.round( 1024 / ( ( new Date() - startTime ) / 1000 ) );
                     // alert(speed);
                    update( speed );
                    index++;
                    //return speed;
                    if( index == iterations ) 
                    {
                        window.clearInterval( timer );
                    };
                };
                            };
            //alert(speed);
            xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
            startTime = new Date();
            xhr.send( data );
            //alert(speed);
            a=((Math.round((fSize*100)/100)*1024));  //showing total image size...
            //alert(a);
            count=a/speed;
            //alert(count);
            return count;
            //alert((Math.round((fSize*100)/100)*1024)+' '+fSExt);
        }     
                /*showing image*/
                    var src = document.getElementById("select_image");
                    var target = document.getElementById("target");
                    showImage(src, target);
                    function showImage(src, target) 
                    {
                        var fr = new FileReader();

                        fr.onload = function (e) 
                        { 
                            target.src = this.result; 
                        };

                            fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
                    }


}
//alert(count);
putImage(count, function ( speed ) 
    {
         //document.getElementById( 'speed' ).textContent = 'speed: ' + speed + 'kbs';
        document.getElementById( 'speed' ).textContent = 'speed: ' + speed;
    } );
</script>
<body>
<div id="speed">speed: 0kbs</div>
<img id="target" />
<input type="file" id="select_image" name="image" onchange="putImage()"> </input>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "display image loading speed"?

Comment: The Mozilla dev site might help with you question and possibly give you the answer that you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart

Comment: your setInterval kicks off `check` once a second - if your uplink speed is anything less than 8mbit/second, you will saturate the uplink connection and probably get inaccurate measurements as a result

Comment: looking at the code, it looks like you've picked bits of several different pieces of code and frankensteined them together to make an abomination that will result in very little useful information

Comment: I means while file uploading at the corner of the page shows total file size and how much uploading completed and how long it will take.That kind of details i want while load one image...  @Akash Agrawal

Comment: Yes i pick this code from different programs,i want result like while loading image loading speed/Size of the image.@JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for showing the progress bar with percentage. For file size, you'll have to do simple calculations like if the file size is 5MB and uploaded percentage is 50% then just divide the file size by 2 and display the uploaded size: 2.5MB /5MB

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxWidth = 400;
    var duration = 3000;
    var $log = $('#log');
    var $start = $('#start');
    var $stop = $('#stop');
    var timer;

    $start.on('click', function() {
        var $bar = $('#bar');
        Horloge(maxWidth);
        timer = setInterval('Horloge('+maxWidth+')', 100);

        $bar.animate({
            width: maxWidth
        }, duration, function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
            $start.attr('disabled', true);
            $stop.attr('disabled', true);
            $log.html('100 %');
            clearInterval(timer);
        });
    });

    $stop.on('click', function() {
        var $bar = $('#bar');
        $bar.stop();

        clearInterval(timer);

        var w = $bar.width();
        var percent = parseInt((w * 100) / maxWidth);
        $log.html(percent + ' %');
    });

});

function Horloge(maxWidth) {
    var w = $('#bar').width();
    var percent = parseInt((w * 100) / maxWidth);
    $('#log').html(percent + ' %');
}
```

```css
body {
 margin:10px;   
}
#bar {
    width:0px;
    height:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>

<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: In this script how can i load the image,here there is no image loading.So kindly send code while start image also will come and also speed like above demo.@Akash Agrawal.